# fileupload control not working in the update panel

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

HI,

fileupload control is inside a grid, When Ajax is not used its s working correctly, so as wen i use a Update panel, am getting a error in uploading my file to thr database, plz help me in this.

Please advice me
Dhanraj.S

Answer (score 4):

You can set Post Back trigger on Submit button. after that you can get image at server side.

for ex.

```
<Triggers>
<ajax:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the `UpdatePanel` does not retain the file inside the `asp:FileUpload`

Workaround is to set a `PostBackTrigger` on the button that updates the `UpdatePanel`

Suppose there is a Button ( lets say UploadFileButton ) that Updates the UpdatePanel. Alter your Panel like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="TestFileUpload" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadFileButton" runat="server" Text="Upload File"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadFileButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the [new AsyncFileUpload Control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) from AjaxControlToolkit 3.5? [Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/10/01/fileupload-in-updatepanel-asp.net-like-gmail.aspx) is a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for but why not use jQuery to upload the file? You can use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to do it. 
This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myForm").ajaxForm({
        success: function (response) {
            $('#updateDiv').append(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://localhost/Default.aspx" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="updateDiv" runat="server">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="filePhoto" name="filePhoto" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
</div>
</form>
```

Of course you will have to handle the form submission in your code-behind and send back the appropriate response.